# include highcharts as a html or image in an export pdf

Tags: javascript, java, ember.js, highcharts

I have to send email to my clients with an attachment that contains *a highchart, an unordered list (side by side) and a table* below these two!
I've gone through many answers that exports highcharts. But I would like to **include the highchart as an image** inside the pdf and continue including unordered list and table.
I'm using **ember.js**!
Please help me with this:(

Comment: Is this something you want to be automated? It seems challenging, you might need to use a scriptable browser’s screenshot function.

Comment: For exporting charts you can use node export server: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server. But for all the rest, you need some third party that allows you to add elements such as images (e.g. in a base64 form) to one PDF document (for example jsPDF: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF).

Comment: you could construct the entire view as an ember page and use `puppeteer` to render it and generate the pdf.